# fs.writeFile while clients try to get the file

Tags: node.js, fs

I'm doing image modifications on a .png and then writing it on my server with

```
fs.writeFile
```

Problem is if some clients try to http get the .png from my server while i'm writing it, it will fail.

How can i prevent that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Save the modified files under a diferent name then rename it to the original name. The rename operation is an atomic one so it will be done instantly.
Steps:

1. Make the modification of `original.png` and write them to `original.png.mod`
2. Rename `original.png.mod` in `original.png`

Comment: Oh that's perfect, i thought `fs.rename` would have the same problem

Comment: No. It's done at the system level. Think of the file path as a pointer to some location on hard drive. On renaming, you don't move the data around, you just change the pointer.

Answer (score 1):

Say you are currently writing to `example.png`.

Write to a different file, and then move it to replace `example.png`.

That removes the lag between opening the file for writing and finishing writing to it.